# "hyper-v requires windows professional" creating Universal App in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just downloaded visual studio 2015 today and was following this tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/dn765018.aspx

Everything was working fine until the third step where an error comes up saying that windows phone emulator can't work without hyper-v and that hyper-v needs windows professional. I understand that, because I made it a windows universal app and that my computer is not windows professional (only windows 8.1) that I can't run the emulator for windows phone. But, because I don't see myself buying another computer or the upgrade or a windows phone any time soon- how can I finish an app on visual studio and run it.

I downloaded visual studio because I was not happy with the limited options in distributing java apps and heard that c# was similar but much better in terms of distributing as an application that people can use. If I can't use visual studio without windows professional then is there any other programming language/platform that will suit me.

Comment: _"how can I finish an app on visual studio and run it"_ -- You can't. You might consider Unity, which has broad cross-platform support and can be tested without a VM (at least, to some extent...I'm not 100% sure of the specifics). All that said, while I understand one's budget is important, if you are intending for this to be a revenue-producing app, a small investment in OS, hardware, or other is easily justified, and if you are not, then you can do your hobby-related work targeting a different platform/environment.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, maybe you mean Xamarin, Unity is specific to games, and I don't see where the OP mentioned he was making a game...

Comment: @RonBeyer: I meant Unity, as it has broader cross-platform support. Xamarin is also a possibility. While Unity is certainly focused on game development, and the programming model is game-centric, it can be used for a wide variety of applications. It's not limited to game development.

Comment: Well, actually I was mainly interested in games but I was also interested in general programming. I heard about unity but I heard a lot of negative stuff about it.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The Pro requirement for Hyper-V is a bit of a bummer, and at odds with the eagerness with which MS is giving all the other tools away. One company, two camps.

Comment: @SayedHajaj: I wouldn't say Unity is the best programming environment around -- due to its game-centric attitude, it has some awkward areas in its API -- but it's free, runs pretty much everywhere, and you can code in C# if you want. That said, see my other comment (under the one answer)...it's not really clear why you are writing a Phone app if you don't want to run it on a phone.

Comment: Neither Unity nor Xamarin will help here as they will also create a package in the end that should be tested on real hardware before published to the store.

Comment: @Stephan: I didn't see anything in the question that indicates the OP wants to publish the app in the store. I agree that software has to be tested, on real hardware, before it's released. But we really don't know _what_ the OP's real goal is here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are completely right. The OP should go a little bit into more detail here.

Comment: Okay, well, I was interested in learning how to develop an app that people can download and run- something better than using th command line. So after I realized how to make jar files, i was interested in something better. I also wanted to make a little money on the side.

Comment: In this case I highly encourage you to get the hardware before publishing an app to the store. With a WP you won't need the emulator but can test right on the device. Even if you get the emulator to run you should always test your apps on real hardware.

Comment: I am not really that interested in windows phone, I want to do for windows pc and then maybe in the future buy an actual windows phone to increase portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The emulator is actually not a real emulator. What happens is that the Windows Phone OS image is running as a virtual image on your PC. According to the [comparison chart for Windows 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx) you really need either Windows 8.1 Pro or Enterprise. As you already mentioned yourself, you will have to upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro (most computers support Hyper-V so it may just be a limitation of your Windows version) or buy a Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible for me to just run it on the computer- instead of making a windows universal to just make a windows desktop or something like that?

Comment: @SayedHajaj: if you don't have a phone, why do you want your program to be a Windows Phone app? You can make it just a plain Windows Store app and it will run fine on your desktop PC.

Comment: You can't run a Windows Phone app in your setup. But sure, you can make a Windows Desktop app as well. Or you develop a Windows Universal Platform app for Windows first. When you later want to run that on a Windows Phone you still have the option to upgrade your Windows license or buy a new Windows Phone. Honestly, you should never publish an app that was never tested on real hardware :)

Comment: Just to clarify, that is what I wanted but when I wanted to debug and run it said something about the windows phone needed to work. I think that this is because the tutorial made me make a universal app that phones can use.

Comment: "The emulator is actually not a real emulator." - Yes it is. It just has some unfortunate requirements.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hmm... maybe it's just me but think of the good old GameBoy. In order to play those games on Windows you need an emulator that emulates the API that the GameBoy operating system provides (translate GB opcodes to x86-64 opcodes). But for the WP "emulator", it is not the case that there is an API that translates ARM opcodes to x86-64 opcodes. The WP OS is actually compiled for x86-64 and runs as a virtual PC directly within Windows (just like you run Linux in VMWare). That's also why WP apps are compiled against x86-64 ro run in the "emulator" and ARM to publish in the store.